# Geo::Google seems dead, fails tests, now what?

Tags: perl, google-maps, cpan

I tried to install Geo::Google using CPAN ( [http://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::Google](http://metacpan.org/pod/Geo%3a%3aGoogle) v0.05 ) and it failed almost all tests. I checked here http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Geo-Google+0.05 and it confirms that this module is **failing everything**.

It seems to be an abandoned module, but I need to **compute the driving distance between 2 addresses from my Perl program**. Any advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am in the process of trying to recover an undermaintained module (Zoidberg) and the best you can do is dig through the results of the CPANtesters to see what went wrong in order to try to fix it.

That said google maps has a public api and even one with a [simple web interface](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/). I will try to mock you up an example, but to get yourself started try doing some requests with [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) or [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize) and then parse out the results to find your answer.

Edit: Ok here is an example. Near the end `$data` is a hashref of the data contained in the JSON response described in the link above. I have also calculated the total distance for the (first) route.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $origin = "60607";
my $destination = "60067";

my $site = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/';
my $mode = 'json';

my $page = $site . $mode . '?origin="' . $origin . '"&destination="' . $destination . '"&sensor=false';

my $response = $ua->get( $page );
my $json = $response->content();

my $data = decode_json $json;

my @legs = @{ $data->{'routes'}[0]{'legs'} };
my $distance_meters = 0;
foreach my $leg (@legs) {
    $distance_meters += $leg->{'distance'}{'value'};
}

my $distance_kilometers = $distance_meters / 1000;
my $distance_miles = $distance_kilometers * 0.62137119;
print $distance_miles . " Miles\n";
```

Edit: And now, since I was bored on a Sunday afternoon:

```
perl -e 'use JSON;use LWP::Simple;($s,$e)=@ARGV;$m+=$_->{distance}{value}for@{(decode_json get qq<http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="$s"&destination="$e"&sensor=false>)->{routes}[0]{legs}};printf"%.2f Miles\n",$m*0.6213e-3' 60607 60067
```

Edit: And now, a port of the one liner to the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) system:

```
perl -Mojo -E '$m+=$_->{distance}{value}for@{g("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json",form=>{origin=>shift,destination=>shift,sensor=>"false"})->json("/routes/0/legs")};printf"%.2f Miles\n",$m*0.6213e-3' 60607 60067
```

Comment: @Slurpie, all in a day's work :-P , actually that one was a little fun

Comment: This is great, thank-you! Exactly what I was looking for. And for those wanting it in metric, just remove the *0.6213e-3 from $m*0.6213e-3, which gives metres instead of miles. The API does seem to support metric vs. imperial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#unit_systems

Comment: This one is a blast from the past. I wonder how much nicer it would look using the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) tools that I usually prefer vs Mechanize/LWP nowadays. :-)

Comment: I am using this code with success but it doesn't seem to like lon and lat coords. The coords are good (verified with goolge) but I get 0 Miles when using coords in one or the other. Looking for some help.